# How to code Network call so that I only return the fields that aren't nil or blank

Tags: json, swift, api, networking

I need to download a recipe's ingredients and measurements. Different recipes have different amounts of ingredients and measurements. The recipe API provides a max number of 20 ingredients objects. Different recipes have different amounts of ingredients. I don't want to show empty or null data. How would I go about coding this to only get the ingredients that aren't empty strings or null.

Hopefully, I explained that well. Please let me know if I need to add more information. I have added the JSON below.

```
 "meals": [
{
  "idMeal": "52772",
  "strMeal": "Teriyaki Chicken Casserole",
  "strDrinkAlternate": null,
  "strCategory": "Chicken",
  "strArea": "Japanese",
  "strInstructions": "Preheat oven to 350° F. Spray a 9x13-inch baking pan with non-stick spray.\r\nCombine soy sauce, ½ cup water, brown sugar, ginger and garlic in a small saucepan and cover. Bring to a boil over medium heat. Remove lid and cook for one minute once boiling.\r\nMeanwhile, stir together the corn starch and 2 tablespoons of water in a separate dish until smooth. Once sauce is boiling, add mixture to the saucepan and stir to combine. Cook until the sauce starts to thicken then remove from heat.\r\nPlace the chicken breasts in the prepared pan. Pour one cup of the sauce over top of chicken. Place chicken in oven and bake 35 minutes or until cooked through. Remove from oven and shred chicken in the dish using two forks.\r\n*Meanwhile, steam or cook the vegetables according to package directions.\r\nAdd the cooked vegetables and rice to the casserole dish with the chicken. Add most of the remaining sauce, reserving a bit to drizzle over the top when serving. Gently toss everything together in the casserole dish until combined. Return to oven and cook 15 minutes. Remove from oven and let stand 5 minutes before serving. Drizzle each serving with remaining sauce. Enjoy!",
  "strMealThumb": "https://www.themealdb.com/images/media/meals/wvpsxx1468256321.jpg",
  "strTags": "Meat,Casserole",
  "strYoutube": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4aZr5hZXP_s",
  "strIngredient1": "soy sauce",
  "strIngredient2": "water",
  "strIngredient3": "brown sugar",
  "strIngredient4": "ground ginger",
  "strIngredient5": "minced garlic",
  "strIngredient6": "cornstarch",
  "strIngredient7": "chicken breasts",
  "strIngredient8": "stir-fry vegetables",
  "strIngredient9": "brown rice",
  "strIngredient10": "",
  "strIngredient11": "",
  "strIngredient12": "",
  "strIngredient13": "",
  "strIngredient14": "",
  "strIngredient15": "",
  "strIngredient16": null,
  "strIngredient17": null,
  "strIngredient18": null,
  "strIngredient19": null,
  "strIngredient20": null,
  "strMeasure1": "3/4 cup",
  "strMeasure2": "1/2 cup",
  "strMeasure3": "1/4 cup",
  "strMeasure4": "1/2 teaspoon",
  "strMeasure5": "1/2 teaspoon",
  "strMeasure6": "4 Tablespoons",
  "strMeasure7": "2",
  "strMeasure8": "1 (12 oz.)",
  "strMeasure9": "3 cups",
  "strMeasure10": "",
  "strMeasure11": "",
  "strMeasure12": "",
  "strMeasure13": "",
  "strMeasure14": "",
  "strMeasure15": "",
  "strMeasure16": null,
  "strMeasure17": null,
  "strMeasure18": null,
  "strMeasure19": null,
  "strMeasure20": null,
  "strSource": null,
  "strImageSource": null,
  "strCreativeCommonsConfirmed": null,
  "dateModified": null
}
```

]
}

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service.  Show what you have done in code, por favor.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such possibility to make it via network call in your case. You have to make a network call just to fetch `Data` object, and then deserialize it. You should know all data chunks that JSON contains in advance. So you need to create model object.  All fields that can be nullable should be marked as Optional value for your structure that you'd like parse into. For example `let strMeasure16: String?`:
And you can build your own logic based on the each value of field:

```
guard let measure = strMeasure16, !measure.isEmpty else {
    print("Value is empty or nil")
    return
}

// do what you need to do with this value
```

It would be much easier if  data provider can structure and send you needed values in Array, if it is possible. If there is no such possibility or you uses open API, only such way. I hope it helped you.